# Failed to rename cache/journal to cache/journal.bkp

Tags: android, caching, okhttp, threadpoolexecutor

I just received this crash report from HockeyApp.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: failed to rename /data/data/com.company.app/cache/journal to /data/data/com.company.app/cache/journal.bkp
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache$1.run(DiskLruCache.java:181)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to rename /data/data/com.company.app/cache/journal to /data/data/com.company.app/cache/journal.bkp
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.io.FileSystem$1.rename(FileSystem.java:85)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.rebuildJournal(DiskLruCache.java:408)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache.access$400(DiskLruCache.java:88)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.DiskLruCache$1.run(DiskLruCache.java:177)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Did you find the steps to reproduce the same? or the solution for this?

Comment: I think this was caused by a memory leak in code loading a full sized image from disk.